# Not continuous on endpoints and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have a general question.

Say $f$ is a real function from $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb R$.
We usually prove continuity on $[a,b]$, but if f were continuous on the open interval $(a,b)$, would there be any issues with differentiability? Do we need continuity on $[a,b]$ in order to have differentiability on (a,b)?

Comment: We don’t even need $f$ to be defined at $a$ or at $b$ for $f$ to be differentiable on $(a,b)$. The reason you will see a lot of theorems that ask for functions that are “continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$” is that they need continuity at the endpoints, but don’t need differentiability there; that is, because they are asking for *less* than they would be asking if they just said “differentiable on $[a,b]$”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let's start from the claim that says that differentiability **at a point** implies continuity at that point. Differentiability on an interval $(a,b)$ is equivalent with differentiability at each point of that interval. This implies that the function is continuous at each point of that interval, i.e. continuous on the interval $(a,b)$. This says nothing about the endpoints.

As an example, consider the function $\tan(x)$. It is continuous on $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$, but not on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (it isn't even defined at the endpoints). Still, it is differentiable on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.